# How to remove the duplicate string?

Tags: java, string, file

In my code I have two files in my drive those two files have some text and I want to display those string in the console and also remove the repeated string and display the repeated string once rather than displaying it twice.

Code:

```
public class read {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        File file = new File("D:\\file1.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Contents of file1:");
        String first = stringBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println(first);

        File file1 = new File("D:\\file2.txt");
        FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(file1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer();
        String line1;
        while((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer1.append(line1);
            stringBuffer1.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader1.close();
        System.out.println("Contents of file2:");
        String second = stringBuffer1.toString();
        System.out.println(second);

        System.out.println("answer:");
        System.out.println(first+second);

    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Output is:

```
answer:
hi hello
how are you
hi ya
i am fine
```

But I want to compare both the strings and if the same string repeated then that string should be displayed once.

Output I expect is like this:

```
answer:
hi hello
how are you
ya
i am fine
```

Where the "hi" is found in both the strings so that I need to delete the one duplicate string. 
How can I do that please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your lines through this method to parse out duplicate words:

```
// store unique previous words
static Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();

static String removeDuplicateWords(String line) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
    // split on whitespace to get distinct words
    for (String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
        // try to add word to the set
        if (words.add(word)) {
            // if the word was added (=not seen before), append to the result
            sj.add(word);
        }
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is StringJoiner Java8?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes. You can use a `StringBuilder` as well, it's just a bit clunkier.

Comment: Indeed, it still has my vote (even though it is only Java8)

Comment: IMHO, the OP question should not be downvoted either

Comment: @ScaryWombat Perhaps, but that takes less commitment. :)